# Geocode get latitude and longitude from google map api using curl in php

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I need to get value of latitude and longitude from google map api by the address. I used the url "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$doctorAddress."&sensor=true" like to get value from google map api. I am trying to get list of values using for loop. But my problem is it return only the null value. I can't able to get the value from API. Is there anyway to get it. Can anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to get the lat and long from google map api using curl in php

```
$address = "India+Panchkula";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=India";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);
echo $lat = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

You can achieve the same with the below method also

```
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);

$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");
$json = json_decode($json);

$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

Comment: Yes i know that. I did the same code but can't able to get value. It should return only the null value.

Comment: @sankar You should have posted the code in question can you post it now,  as the above code is working for me

Comment: @sankar After your comment i have tested it once more and it give me output 30.6942091
76.860565.

Just to confirm is curl enabled?

Comment: okay fine. i am getting the following error Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Comment: I used file_get_contents... Now am getting Fatal error:Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in php

Comment: @sankar First thing where is your curl code in question i asked you to please update it and then is curl enabled or not.

And if you are getting execution time error you need to increase execution time on your server

Comment: {
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
} am getting the above message. is there any other way to resolve this.